# SMS verification with Android SmsRetrieverClient not parsing message

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, sms-verification

Tried to implement SMS auto-reading for verification following the steps here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request

1) declared

```
lateinit var smsRetrieverClient: SmsRetrieverClient
private lateinit var smsReceiver: SmsBrReceiver
```

2) Initialised and registered them in login Activity onCreate

```
smsRetrieverClient = SmsRetriever.getClient(this)
smsReceiver = SmsBrReceiver()

val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
intentFilter.addAction(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
applicationContext.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter)

val task = smsRetrieverClient.startSmsRetriever()
task.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Void> {
    smsReceiver.setTimeout()
})
task.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e ->
    showCodeInput()
})
```

3) Made BroadcastReceiver for SmsRetriever

```
inner class SmsBrReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    var h = Handler()
    var r: Runnable = Runnable { doTimeout() }

    fun setTimeout() {
        h.postDelayed(r, 600000)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {

        val action = intent.action

        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == action) {

            cancelTimeout()
            val extras = intent.extras
            val status = extras!!.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status
            when (status.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> { // not called
```

4) The SMS comes in format

```
\u200b\u200bPlease enter code: 1111 /appKeyXf56
```

And the app key at the end of SMS matches what the installed app signing key gives for generation as described here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS does not get called after SMS is received, but CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT does get called after 5 minutes.

What is missing? Just in case gradle declarations for phone auth are:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to shorten the message, although it seemed to not be over 140 bytes. After making the SMS text to ~30 characters auto-read of SMS works without other changes.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me so much debugging time

Comment: Official doc said:
>Be no longer than 140 bytes
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify

Comment: 140 bytes is a deceptively short message. And it's not like we can easily measure that, you kind of need to experiment

Comment: 140 byes is the standard sms limit though, anymore and it's not a single sms anymore, even if the client hides that complexity from most users now.